# DDD: Where should I set modified date and modified by? Repository or application service?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Where should I set fields like CreatedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy? Should I pass current user context to repository and set it there or maybe better way is to set it in application service (but then it must be done in each API method rather than only in Add/Update in repository)?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your domain.

If values like `CreatedDate`, `CreatedBy`... are for tracking or logging purpose, then I'd place them in the `Infrastructure` (Repository).

On the other hand, if these values belong to my domain for any reason, then I'd place them in the domain layer.

Example: imaging that in a Banking Transfer context, a customer could cancel a transfer only until 24 hours after submit it for settlement. Then the domain needs `CreateTransferDate` to satisfy the invariants.

Another option could be a listener that consume all domain events and save historial time data of what happen.

Answer (score 3):

CreatedDate, CreatedBy, ModifiedDate and ModifiedBy are typically concepts that have no real domain value, but they are more like a technical concept; and that's why I typically don't set these in application or domain layer, but in repository layer. After all, the repository layer is a technical layer. In a domain I don't care about this kind of information. Unless of course, it's part of the ubiquitous language, but mostly it's not.

Also, if ModifiedDate would be part of the domain/application, you would have to set it with each manipulation you do, which would be very tedious and error-prone. If you do it in the repository, it's easier, because you do it with every update.

So I would ask the question: does business care about it?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer setting them in the repository. Add one parameter in existing add/update method named `int operatorId` or something similar.

If you put the code in application service, you need to always repeat yourself. And if you forget to set some values, exceptions will be thrown when changes are saved (sometimes even worse, no exceptions but dirty data).

Comment: We never allow entites to be in an invalid state. We do this by enforcing design by contract checks, (pre-conditions, invariants and post conditions where applicable). That way you ensure no-one can "forget" to set values

Answer (score 0):

We always set entity state inside application services. Repositories are for saving data, they should not contain any logic. The domain entity is created/modified in the application service, therefore that is where you set these fields. The creation/modification dates should not reflect when the entity was saved to the database, but rather when the entity was actually saved/modified.

Also, we find that we usually have to map our domain entities to data layer entities to be more friendly with the underlying database technology. We often use tools like automapper help us automate these mappings. Having fields in an entity that do not exist in its data entity equivalent adds unnecessary complexity

Comment: "Repositories are for saving data, they should not contain any logic", so you think a `StudentRepository` has a method named `GetStudents(int grade)` is incorrect because it has the logic of getting students by their grade?

Comment: I assume bstrack means "Domain-Business logic"